# How to get a file content as a textarea value?

Tags: php, html

**test.php**

```
<div class='btitle'>LOREM</div>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php $story = file_get_contents('test.php'); ?>
<textarea class='txa' value = <?php echo $story; ?>></textarea>
```

**result**
what I see inside textarea:

```
LOREM</div>
>
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do like this:-

```
<textarea class='txa'> <?php echo $story; ?> </textarea>
```

Just to show you why i have written in above way:

```js
console.log($('textarea').val())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class='txa'> 123 </textarea>
```

Note:- if `$story` has some markup - it could break html and probably you needs to use `htmlspecialchars()`

Comment: Also you can mention that if `$story` has some html markup - it could break html and probably OP needs to use `htmlspecialchars`.

Comment: textarea don't have `value` attribute

Comment: @u_mulder  yes, added that. Thanks for useful input

Comment: @AlivetoDie, if textarea don't have `value` attribute, how is possible to set its content using `$('#txa').val('something')` ? Also `<textarea value = '323'></textarea>` - works.

Comment: Don't be confuse, means to say `text` inside textarea is treated as `value`

Answer (score 0):

I do:

```
enter code here
   <?php $story = explode(PHP_EOL,file_get_contents('test.php'));foreach $story as $line) $text .= $line.'<br>'; ?>
enter code here
```

`<textarea class='txa'> <?=$text ; ?> </textarea>`

Comment: And what's this for? `<br>`s are __not processed__ inside `textarea`. Also, if you need newlines - there's `nl2br` so you `foreach` is useless.